# Eval in class (include)

Tags: php, preg-replace

In a class get function from a database table, `View::getContentByLink` I would like to use a special code like 'BB'.

`[img=1,2,3,4,5] ==> $this->getIMG($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);`

`[inc=string] ==> include("string.php");`

First I made a function for `preg_replace` (It is working):

```
private function showCodes($text) {
    $find = array(
        '~\[img=(.*?)\]~s',
        '~\[inc=(.*?)\]~s'
    );

    $replace = array(
        '<?php $this->getImg($1);?>',
        '<?php include("inc/$1.inc.php");?>'
    );

    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```

AND in function `getContentByLink` I do:

```
$str = "Just test with codes [inc=test_string] and pics [img=1,2,3,4,5]";

eval("?>\r\n $str \r\n<?php");
// This two are two different attempts I've tried
//eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
//eval("return $str");
```

The `View::getIMG` function works fine and is irrelevant right now. In this code the `include('test_string.php')` works fine! But the `getImg` is not.

`var_dump` returned:

> View.class.php:74:string 'Just test with codes OK and pics getImg(1,2,3,4,5);?>' (length=71)

The returned html source code:

```
.(...)Just test with codes OK and pics <?php
```

maybe using `$this` is wrong.. I've tried using `$View` (I called with this variable in the script)...

Where running the `imgGet` function with eval in class def script or the main where called the View class?

Comment: Updated:

in the showCodes function (in replace array) replaced and working fine:
`<?php $tempView=new View;  echo $tempView->getImgSized($1,$2,$3,$4,"$5"); unset($tempView)?>`